# E-Core clock of 12900k is very high on idle state

Tags: cpu, clock

I noticed that none of E-core clock of my 12900k goes under 3.7GHz.

Here's a screenshot of idle state from HWINFO64:

[image: CPU Clock]

As you can see, even though every P-core shows 400MHz, each E-core clock is 3.7GHz.

Is this high clock of E-core in idle state expected behavior?
Can I make it lower on idle state?

For your information, I have installed 12900k on MSI Z690I UNIFY motherboard.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare how two very different cores are running?  What makes you think the E-Core should down clock itself? Are you using a version of HWINFO64 that supports 12th Intel hardware?

Comment: And why is this a concern? Is power usage at idle excessive? Is the CPU overheating?

Comment: E-Cores are supposedly already very efficient on electricity. Why do they need to down-clock?

Comment: I don't know anything about E-Core's behavior. I cannot find any reference or specification which explains E-Core clock range. I just want to  know this is normal. @Ramhound I don't know but I think it supports 12th because I have installed latest one.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It just works well. If it is usual case, I won't care it anymore.

Comment: @harrymc I don't need. I just want to know about my hardware.

Comment: To rule out the obvious, "it's a software bug", can you use different software?

Comment: @Ramhound I cannot check it right now, but I think hardware monitoring sensors in aquasuite showed same values, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Your processor shouldn’t actually be throttling itself down to 400 MHz your asking the wrong question.